# getting method not found setTime(long) in AlarmManager when tried to set time and date in android system time

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I'm trying to set the system time and date on an Android device.

I thought the following code would work, but it produces the error `method not found: setTime(long)`

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(2010, 1, 1, 12, 00, 00);
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setTime(c.getTimeInMillis());
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible for an application to change the date or time on an (non-rooted) Android device.

From the documentation for `AlarmManager.setTime()`:

> Requires the permission android.permission.SET_TIME.

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Comment: i set permission.SET_TIME in my Manifest file. Still facing this issue. My device is not rooted. Is there any way to set time and date for device which is not rooted?

Comment: No, as I said quite clearly in my answer. It is impossible for an application to change the date or time. Period. Not possible. No way. None.

Comment: @DavidWasser ... unless the phone is rooted, in which case you can do it with the NDK if not via Java.

Comment: @CraigRinger if you read my answer you will see **on an (non-rooted) Android devic** so I think I already said that.

Comment: @DavidWasser Ah, sorry, I'm blind.

Answer (score -1):

> This may Helpful 
>   ------------------Broad Cast Class----------------------------

```
public class TimeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {

    Toast.makeText(ctx, "It's time to WAKE UP!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

> ----------------Write this code in Activity Class --------------------------

```
PendingIntent sender = null;
    Intent intent = null;
    Calendar systemtime = Calendar.getInstance();
    systemtime.setTime(new Date());

    Calendar timeToTriggerAlarm = Calendar.getInstance();
    timeToTriggerAlarm.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, systemtime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
    timeToTriggerAlarm.set(Calendar.MINUTE, systemtime.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
    timeToTriggerAlarm.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

    intent = new Intent(this,TimeReceiver.class);

    sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeToTriggerAlarm.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
```

> Note- Opent your manifest file and click on option>Add>Reciever>brows>addclassname(here is TimeReceiver)

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question. The poster wants to know how he can change the date and time on the phone programatically. Not how to wake up his phone at a particular time.