# Change time / date settings on android?

Tags: java, android

I have created an application that changes the date/time settings on Android, but if I test it, it doesn't work.

Is that because of security from system inside android, or is something wrong?

Here is my code:

```
if (killed) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    AlarmManager a = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    long current_time_milliens = System.currentTimeMillis();
try {
    a.setTime((long) current_time_milliens - 86400);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // add exception handling
}
```

Comment: Looks like it's not possible. Read this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11708781/2065418

Comment: "it don't works" provides us with no information. Does your real code catch and swallow exceptions like that? If so, that's the first thing to change - an exception may well be thrown with really useful information, and you've no idea...

Comment: It don't works yes, is there something wrong with that ?
I just post my code and said that it's not possible to change date / time with it...
and i wanted to know if this was normal because android system is locked that possibility ?

Comment: @Amoniks 1st change ur system time. after u will get app time

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change this unless it is a system app (protection level signatureOrSystem) or your phone is rooted (since there is a protection in the linux layer). This means that if it is a regular Play app, it is not possible. Also, if you would succeed in having the above requirements, your app also needs the permission android.permission.SET_TIME.

The only way to change time from a non-system app is to let the user set it manually:

```
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_DATE_SETTINGS));
```

Answer (score 0):

David Wasser has answered a similar question;

"It is not possible for an application to change the date or time on an (non-rooted) Android device.

From the documentation for AlarmManager.setTime():

> Requires the permission android.permission.SET_TIME.

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html"

Original Comment:
[getting method not found setTime(long) in AlarmManager when tried to set time and date in android system time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12104213/getting-method-not-found-settimelong-in-alarmmanager-when-tried-to-set-time-an)